# New LWC component - No MODULE named progressRing found

Tags: lightning-web-components, spring-20

The new [lightning-progress-ring](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-progress-ring/example) is available as of v48.0 (Spring '20 release).

I've put it in my LWC html file like so:

```
...
<div class="slds-media__figure">
    <lightning-progress-ring value="100" variant="base-autocomplete"> </lightning-progress-ring>
</div>
...
```

Yet when I deploy it to a dev org that's on Spring '20 using `sfdx force:source:deploy`, I get the following message:

```
PROBLEM: No MODULE named progressRing found
```

I've set the `.meta` on the LWC to 48.0 as well as the related Apex controller.

I also did `sfdx update` to have the most recent CLI.  It looks like it installed correctly, but threw an interesting error at me (not sure if it's related though):

```
gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/anunim/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.3.0
gyp ERR! command \"/Users/anunim/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.46.3-4cf515d568/bin/node\" \"/usr/local/bin/node-gyp\" \"rebuild\"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/anunim/.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v6.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok"
```

Question: What am I missing to be able to deploy this to my developer org?  Could this potentially be a bug associated with the new release?

Comment: What does `sfdx version` say? It needs to also be at version 48.0 or weird things like this can happen.

Comment: @sfdcfox `sfdx-cli/7.46.3-4cf515d568 darwin-x64 node-v10.15.3` :shrug:  POZ seems to have confirmed it's an actual bug - see the answer below

Comment: Yeah, I saw the edit right after my comment. Hopefully it'll be an easy fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that your project configuration file (`sfdx-project.json`) has `"sourceApiVersion": "48.0"`

**EDIT** I confirm that it's a bug I can reproduce with issue with a scratch org. I'll reach out to the component owner.

Comment: Still getting the same error.  I think the `sfdx-project.json` version is only relevant to scratch orgs or the extensions within VS Code.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Nice, thank you for reaching out and calming my nerves about this.  I'll wait to hear back

Comment: Just ran into this as well.

Comment: @POZ Any updates from engineering? Trying to do a release by week's end and want to know if I need to do a full workaround in the meantime

Comment: The issue is fixed internally but I don't know when the patch will be deployed.

Comment: Forward looking statement: that should de deployed between Feb 25th and 27th depending on your instance.

Comment: Thank you for following up here, I really appreciate it.  Safe harbor: Just in time for our package release! :sweat-smile: